# Adding money to all user's accounts

Tags: php, mysql, database

we have a social network that consists of several user types and we want to add $7.04 to all customer accounts to celebrate the USA holiday 4th of July.

I have used the following SQL command:

```
    UPDATE `database`.`databasename` SET fCreditAmount = fCreditAmount + 7.04 WHERE eUserType = 'C'
```

However when I do this it seems to credit multiple times.  So instead of just giving each customer $7.04 it credits some customers $1000s.

Anyone know why this is occurring?

Our 'balance' table structure is:

```
iBalanceId (autoincrement)
iUserId
eUserType
eBalType
fCreditAmount
fDebitAmount
dEntryDate
dValueDate
vDescritption
vBalTypeCode
iRefId
vRefTypeCode
iAddedUserId
eAddedUserType
vProcessDescription 
eBalanceStatus
```

Comment: At first glance I'm 90% convinced that the issue comes from something you didn't expect in the data.  Can you please show us before and after `SELECT iUserId, fCreditAmount FROM database.databasename WHERE eUserType = 'C';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more information, but it looks like you're adding $7.04 to every transaction in a user's history. So each user is getting `7.04 * numberOfTransactions` in credit.

You should be adding a new transaction (an INSERT) in the desired amount. That way, each account will get the credit exactly once.

I certainly hope you didn't do this on your production database!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening.  The command is adding $7.04 to every transaction in a user's history.  Would the proper SQL command be:

Comment: INSERT `database`.`databasename` SET fCreditAmount = fCreditAmount + 7.04 WHERE eUserType = 'C'

Comment: @SinCats You need to have `INSERT INTO`, not just `INSERT`, and there's no `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement. Your query would be something like `INSERT INTO databaseName.tableName SET fCreditAmount = 7.04, eUserType = 'C', someOtherColumn = ...`. You will want to initialize other column names as appropriate (but we can't help you with that, based on the very limited information here). You may want to brush up on [the MySQL INSERT statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).

Comment: @SinCats Anyway, if this helped, please remember to accept an answer. You can always ask additional questions if you need further help, and link to this one if it helps provide context.

Comment: INSERT INTO databse.table SET fCreditAmount = 7.04, eUserType = 'C'

Comment: But it only inserted one record

Comment: @SinCats Well, yes, if you only did one INSERT statement. You're going to have to INSERT one record per customer. There are lots of ways to do this, but that's what has to happen based on your database design. The best way is going to be to create a temporary table, do an `INSERT INTO temporaryTableName SELECT DISTINCT (whatever your columns are for identifying a customer, probably iUserId) FROM databaseName.tableName`, then `INSERT INTO databaseName.tableName SELECT (column names) FROM temporaryTableName`. How to do that is way beyond the scope of your question.